# Problems using captured access token to retrieve user's facebook information

Tags: c#, winforms, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have been attempting to code a windows form application that interacts with facebook to retrieve the access token that has permissions to get some of the user's information. I have been trying to get the birthday of myself using the following code but it keeps giving me the 400 bad request error. Basically after running this code, and logging in at the authentication it is suppose to show a messagebox containing the user's birthday. In this case, I am using my own user id in the api.GET method. It seems to be the access token issue as when I don't pass in any tokens, i can view public available information such as id using the same code but I print out the access token to check and it seems to be alright. Any help would be much appreciated. First time posting here

```
public partial class AccessTokenRetrieval : Form
{
    private string accessToken=null;


    public AccessTokenRetrieval()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void accessTokenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string getAccessTokenURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=223055627757352&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=user_photos,offline_access";
        getAccessTokenWebBrowser.Navigate(getAccessTokenURL);
    }

    private void getAccessTokenWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        string successUrl = @"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        string urlContainingUserAuthKey = e.Url.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(urlContainingUserAuthKey);

        int searchInt = urlContainingUserAuthKey.IndexOf(successUrl);
        MessageBox.Show(searchInt.ToString());

        if (urlContainingUserAuthKey.IndexOf(successUrl) == -1)
        {
            string accessTokenString;
            accessTokenString = Regex.Match(urlContainingUserAuthKey, "access_token=.*&").ToString();
            this.accessToken = accessTokenString.Substring(13, accessTokenString.Length - 14);
            //100001067570373
            //MessageBox.Show(accessToken);
            accessTokenTextBox.Text = this.accessToken;
            Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(this.accessToken);
            JSONObject me = api.Get("/100001067570373");
            MessageBox.Show(me.Dictionary["user_birthday"].String);
        }
    }
```

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would request you to try http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com and checkout the samples folder. 
It includes sample for WinForms authentication and also making various request to Facebook.

Here are other useful links that I would recommend you to read.

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Making-Requests.aspx